# JSpinner Date Editor in Buddhist Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, jspinner

Is there a way to use JSpinner.DateEditor with a Buddhist Calendar?  When I change my locale to "th", "TH" and recreate my calendars they are indeed Buddhist Calendars.  However, the JSpinners are not updated.  Here is some sample code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("th", "TH");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
// Reinitializing calendars with new locale, this is done correctly
encodingCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
expirationCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// Modifying the spinners in another class to update them with the correct locale
// this is the part that's not doing what I'd expect.
editor.getExpirationDateSpinner().setLocale(locale);
editor.getExpirationDateSpinner().getEditor().setLocale(locale);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the spinner's locale:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class JSpinnerTest extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("JSpinnerTest");
                f.add(new JSpinnerTest());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JSpinnerTest() {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setLocale(new Locale("th", "TH"));
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date initDate = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5);
        Date earliestDate = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
        Date latestDate = calendar.getTime();
        spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(
            initDate, earliestDate, latestDate, Calendar.MONTH));
        spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "MMM yyyy"));
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSpinner s = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
                label.setText(s.getValue().toString());
            }
        });
        label.setText(initDate.toString());
        this.add(label);
        this.add(spinner);
    }
}
```

[image: JSpinnerTest]

Comment: I've already tried updating the locale as I posted in my example code.  I tried recreating the SpinnerDateModel with new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(expirationCalendar.getTime(), null, null, Calendar.MONTH), but that didn't work.

Comment: I believe you have to set the *spinner's* locale. I've added an SSCCE & screenshot.