# Java Swing JTable cell in "edit" mode uses different set of settings?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have set some parameters for my JTable, but it seems they are in effect only in what I call "view" mode. When editing cell content, nothing works.

In the screenshot below you can see how the font size reverted back to default. (Large one is what I set and what I want to see).

Also, I have default Locale set to Germany so that my decimal numbers would use commas as in 12,24 (instead of US 12.24 style) - which also stops working as soon as I try editing cell. It reverts back to US dot style, and after I hit Enter it gets displayed with comma again. E.g. if I enter 12,24 cell does not accept it as invalid double. But when I enter 12.24, after I hit Enter, it is displayed as 12,24 - proper German style :)

So in short it looks like cell-in-editing-mode uses a different set of settings... how can I change those or, preferably, make it use the same as in non-editing mode?

[cell behavior http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/9118/jtablebehavior.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/9118/jtablebehavior.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the locale on the component itself, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010098/jspinner-date-editor-in-buddhist-calendar/2010819#2010819). For better control you can define your own cell editor, as discussed in this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). In addition to the examples there, here is a complete [editor/renderer example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).