# JSpinner: when I used the method "getValue()" it returns me the date of the 1th January 1974

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I'm in trouble with a problem of the Java JSpinner.
If I do not modify the value which is displayed in the spinner everything works.
But if I change the value (a date) using the arrows my program returns to me the date of 1th January 1970.

Here's the snippet of code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class GUI {

JSpinner mySpinner;



public void createGUI(){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    panel.setSize(300,100);
    mySpinner=new JSpinner();
    mySpinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.MINUTE));
    mySpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(mySpinner, "HH:mm"));
    mySpinner.setBounds(0, 0, 71, 28);

    final JLabel myLabel=new JLabel();
    panel.add(myLabel);

    mySpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            System.out.println("JSpinner: "+mySpinner.getValue());

        }

    });


    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(mySpinner);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

This is the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GUI myGUI=new GUI();
    myGUI.createGUI();
}
```

And this is what console prints:

```
JSpinner: Thu Jan 01 23:03:00 CET 1970
JSpinner: Thu Jan 01 22:03:00 CET 1970
```

Comment: You've got a bug somewhere in your code, likely in code not shown us. I suggest that you consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also some unrelated recommendations: you will want to  avoid use of null layout as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. Also I would not name my JSpinner formattedTextField as that would be confusing.

Comment: Actually I was wrong -- your description is enough to show the problem. I've posted code, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that I think reproduces it.

Comment: I rewrite the code as you suggest. Now it's more simple.

Comment: Check MadProgrammer's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14455065/522444) to a similar question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set todays date to `DateEditor`. Try following snippet.

```
Date today = new Date();
JSpinner s = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel(today, null, null,
    Calendar.MINUTE));
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(s, "HH:mm");
s.setEditor(de);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you tested your suggestion? I have, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I have tested my suggestion and then posted it. Should I post full class and sysout?

Comment: Blackpanther,
I try using your code but it doesn't work.
The console shows the data from the first Jan 1970

Comment: Swapril, test your recommendations with the original poster's code. If yours works, then yes, post your whole small program here and notify us by comment.