# JPopupMenu not appearing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpopupmenu, japplet

I have a Java applet that will consist of several popup menus that the user will have to interact with. However, the JPopupMenu won't show up when added. Here is my code:

```
public class Parser extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPopupMenu deviceMenu;
    JButton downloadButton;
    Map <String, Object> deviceDict;

    public void init () {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createGUI();
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.println("createGUI didn't successfully complete");
        }
    }
    public void createGUI() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("[URL]");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            String xml = "";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                xml = xml + inputLine;
        deviceDict = Plist.fromXml(xml);
        System.out.print(deviceDict);
        } 

        catch (XmlParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 360));
        setSize(480, 360);
        Iterator <String> deviceIterator = deviceDict.keySet().iterator();
        deviceMenu = new JPopupMenu("Test");
        while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(deviceIterator.next());
            deviceMenu.add(item);
        }
        add(deviceMenu);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: use JComboBox, not JPopupMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use a JComboBox instead of JPopupMenu

Answer (score 3):

When do you want it to show up?
You need to call [show()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29) if you want to display the popup menu.
See this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpleexampleofJPopupMenu.htm) and [the one from oracle site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).

BTW - from your question it seems [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I see. I was confused about what JPopupMenu actually does. If i want the kind of menu hat essentially has a button that when clicked displays a JPopupMenu, is there an Object for that or will I have to just make it be a button?

Comment: If I get you right - You will need to create each of them using JMenuItem.

Comment: What I want is something that will represent like this: http://i.imgur.com/VCal4.png , where clicking on it will show the JPopupMenu.

Comment: This one is called JComboBox.

Comment: that's JSpinner http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Comment: @mKorbel - unless I am blind - this is JComboBox :)

Comment: @MByD @mKorbel I agree with both of you guys this is a JComboBox that looks like JSpinner since it is apple customised combobox. :)

Comment: @MByD +1 for answer and comments. Good stuff.

Comment: @ MByD the why OP find out JPopupMenu funcionalities for something what s/he wants, and we are now voting if is that "half JComboBox/half JSpinner" :-)

Comment: @MByD it is all please my friend. PS: you are like a lightning on all the questions. Your average response time is less then 5 mins. Good job. :)

Comment: @Boro mKorbel - `:D` @Boro - Thanks, I think I should get a life :)

Comment: @MByD Knowledge is power. Having brains that help you to sort out problems, like lots of people here on stack, helps lots to many in an unmeasurable way. Keep up the good work. It is appreciated. PS: the real life can wait :)

Comment: @mKobel: For reference, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010098/jspinner-date-editor-in-buddhist-calendar/2010819#2010819) is a `JSpinner` in the same L&F, `aqua`.

Comment: @ MByD  agreed,  hmmm link http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/ from todays thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008058/customizing-jtextfield , one big sorry man