# Change JButton Shape while respecting Look And Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, paint

I know this question has been asked a million times, and can be done by overriding `paintComponent()`, but what I want to know is how to change the shape while respecting the current Look And Feel. If I want to change the shape to a circle, I also want the button to look like a button, just with a different shape.

I tried making a JButton, the overriding `paintComponent`, then clipping it to a circle, but I didn't get the border effects on `Nimbus LAF`.

Is there a better way? Or is there a method in `JButton`?

Comment: [`PieceButton`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979) has a round `Icon` that may get you started on your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: A component is unique for every LAF. So the shape/size/color/font is unique for every LAF. If you want to change the shape of a component then you need to rewrite the UI for the given LAF.  Unless your LAF supports a Circle Border then you won't be able to do this. There is no shortcut. You need to write all the code.

Comment: @camickr How do you do that without knowing the current `LAF`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drawing components a ComponentUI is used. This UI class has a paint method and is used to paint the component. The paint method uses the settings of the L&F which are stored as properties in the UIManager.

To create your own component `RoundButton` extending from e.g. `AbstractButton` you can create your own `RoundButtonUI` (maybe extending from `ButtonUI`). Here you can create your own paint method using the properties of a normal button like `Button.font` or `Button.foreground` to draw your own component with the same L&F values as a normal button.

In your `RoundButton` class you should implement the method `getUIClassID()` which will return the string `"RoundButtonUI"`. This causes your `RoundButtonUI` to be used.

A good example is `JButton` itself.

Comment: I guess this could be it although it still doesn't make the shaped button look perfect

Comment: I used it a lot when we made a new L&f, you have to take care all the border and insets etc. are correct, to make the LayoutManager handle the component correctly. Maybe you can post your code.

Comment: Thanks, I got it with some tweaking. I think it look nice, and it still keeps the border effects thanks to how `Nimbus` is written!