# How to make a Round Rectangle JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

I want to make a round rectangle JTextField. I write a sub class of AbstractBorder to realize it.But I run into some problems.
My requirement is:
[image]

What I get is:

[image]

My code is :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class JTextFieldTest {
    JTextField textField;
    boolean activate = false;

    public void createUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test JTextField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextFieldTest jTextFieldTest = new JTextFieldTest();
        jTextFieldTest.createUI();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class MainPanel extends JPanel{
        public MainPanel(){

            textField = new JTextField("Please input:");
            Font fieldFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);
            textField.setFont(fieldFont);
            textField.setBackground(Color.white);
            textField.setForeground(Color.gray.brighter());

            textField.setColumns(30);
            textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new CustomeBorder(), 
new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20))));
            textField.addActionListener(new FieldListener());
            textField.addMouseListener(new FieldMouseListener());

            add(textField,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setBackground(Color.blue);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class CustomeBorder extends AbstractBorder{
        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y,
                int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 20, 20);
        }

    }

    class FieldListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(textField.getText());
        }

    }

    class FieldMouseListener implements MouseListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(activate == false){
                textField.setText("");
            }
            activate = true;
            textField.setForeground(Color.black);


        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

I can get another effect by using

> textField.setOpaque(false);
>
> g.setColor(Color.white);
>   g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, 20, 20);

Another effect is:
[image]

In sum, what can I do to realize my requirement?

@Arijit, it's the effect of your solution when it runs on my computer.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can add g.fillRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, 20, 20); to the last solution and use background color there

Comment: @StanislavL. It will cover the JTextfield and any input can't be seen anymore.

Comment: @StanislavL. It's still a solution if I use g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,100)) but it's just not as same as the requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `TextBubbleBorder`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

class TextBubbleBorder extends AbstractBorder {

    private Color color;
    private int thickness = 4;
    private int radii = 8;
    private int pointerSize = 7;
    private Insets insets = null;
    private BasicStroke stroke = null;
    private int strokePad;
    private int pointerPad = 4;
    RenderingHints hints;

    TextBubbleBorder(
        Color color) {
            this(color, 4, 8, 7);
    }

    TextBubbleBorder(
        Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize) {
            this.thickness = thickness;
            this.radii = radii;
            this.pointerSize = pointerSize;
        this.color = color;

        stroke = new BasicStroke(thickness);
        strokePad = thickness/2;

        hints = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int pad = radii + strokePad;
        int bottomPad = pad + pointerSize + strokePad;
        insets = new Insets(pad,pad,bottomPad,pad);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        return getBorderInsets(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(
        Component c,
        Graphics g,
        int x, int y,
        int width, int height) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        int bottomLineY = height-thickness-pointerSize;

        RoundRectangle2D.Double bubble = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
            0+strokePad,
            0+strokePad,
            width-thickness,
            bottomLineY,
            radii,
            radii
            );

        Polygon pointer = new Polygon();

        // left point
        pointer.addPoint(
            strokePad+radii+pointerPad,
            bottomLineY);
        // right point
        pointer.addPoint(
            strokePad+radii+pointerPad+pointerSize,
            bottomLineY);
        // bottom point
        pointer.addPoint(
            strokePad+radii+pointerPad+(pointerSize/2),
            height-strokePad);

        Area area = new Area(bubble);
        area.add(new Area(pointer));

        g2.setRenderingHints(hints);

        Area spareSpace = new Area(new Rectangle(0,0,width,height));
        spareSpace.subtract(area);
        g2.setClip(spareSpace);
        g2.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        g2.setClip(null);

        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(stroke);
        g2.draw(area);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JTextField o = new JTextField(
                    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!");

                o.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.MAGENTA.darker(),2,4,0));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, o);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution but do you know how to improve my solution?BTW,why textField.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.pink)); throw a java.lang.NullPointerException?

Comment: *"why textField.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.pink)); throw a java.lang.NullPointerException"*  Oops!  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution and I don't need to use

> textField.setOpaque(false);

I just use the following code to fill the space.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CustomeBorder extends AbstractBorder{
    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y,
            int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
        super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2d.setColor(new Color(68,184,224));
        g2d.drawRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, 20, 20);
    }   
}
```

You should adjust the width of BasicStroke based on your JTextField.
The final result is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use this:

```
JTextField Mytxtfield = new JTextField()
        {protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) 
            {
                if ( !isOpaque( ) )
                {
                    super.paintComponent( g );
                    return;
                }

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

                GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                    0, 0, color1,
                    0, 20, color2);

                g2d.setPaint( gp );
               // g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
                g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 10, 10);


                setOpaque( false );
                super.paintComponent( g );
                setOpaque( true );
            }};
```

Full Working code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class DBconnection extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;



    private JTextField textFieldHost;

    private Color color2 = Color.white;
    private Color color1 = Color.white;


    public DBconnection() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        setTitle("Connect To MDM Database");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(450, 200, 410, 280);


        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        textFieldHost = new JTextField()
        {protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) 
            {
                if ( !isOpaque( ) )
                {
                    super.paintComponent( g );
                    return;
                }

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

                GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                    0, 0, color1,
                    0, 20, color2);

                g2d.setPaint( gp );
               // g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
                g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 10, 10);


                setOpaque( false );
                super.paintComponent( g );
                setOpaque( true );
            }};
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldHost = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textFieldHost.insets = new Insets(20, 40, 5, 0);
        gbc_textFieldHost.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textFieldHost.gridwidth=3;
        gbc_textFieldHost.gridx = 2;
        gbc_textFieldHost.gridy = 4;
        gbc_textFieldHost.ipady=5;
        contentPane.add(textFieldHost, gbc_textFieldHost);
        textFieldHost.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2,2,2));



}


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DBconnection frame = new DBconnection();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }




}
```

Also by changing the value of color1 and color2, you can get a gradient effect.

I have modified your code and get this:
[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;


public class JTextFieldTest {
    JTextField textField;
    boolean activate = false;

    public void createUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test JTextField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextFieldTest jTextFieldTest = new JTextFieldTest();
        jTextFieldTest.createUI();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class MainPanel extends JPanel{
        public MainPanel(){

            textField = new JTextField("Test JTextField")
            {protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) 
            {
                if ( !isOpaque( ) )
                {
                    super.paintComponent( g );
                    return;
                }

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

                GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                    0, 0, Color.white,
                    0, 20, Color.white);

                g2d.setPaint( gp );
               // g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
                g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 20, 20);


                setOpaque( false );
                super.paintComponent( g );
                setOpaque( true );
            }};
            textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            Font fieldFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);
            textField.setFont(fieldFont);


            textField.setColumns(30);

            textField.addActionListener(new FieldListener());
            textField.addMouseListener(new FieldMouseListener());

            add(textField,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setBackground(Color.blue);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        }
    }



    class FieldListener implements ActionListener{


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(textField.getText());
        }

    }

    class FieldMouseListener implements MouseListener{

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(activate == false){
                textField.setText("");
            }
            activate = true;
            textField.setForeground(Color.black);


        }


        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution seems not stable.You can test by input some chars  in the textfield.

Comment: But its working for me. tell me what issue are you getting after entering inputs?

Comment: I add the effect of your solution on my question.

Comment: I've tried your new solution but it's still not stable.It appears to be ideal when it's launched but some transformation will happen if you just do some operation of the JTextField.

Comment: I think its rendering problem, call repaint after doing any transformation.

Comment: @Arijit.Transformation here means the change of the round rectangle,I will show you at the question.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54612/discussion-between-upma-and-arijit).