# Java Date Picker with different calendar system

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, calendar, datepicker

Is there a J2SE date picker (e.g. JCalendar or JXDatePicker) that be able to use a calendar system other that Gregorian?
For example [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/) library has [Calendar](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/Calendar.html) classes that supports different calendar systems ([Gregorian](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/GregorianCalendar.html), [Hebrew](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/HebrewCalendar.html), [Jalali](http://sourceforge.net/projects/persiancalendar/), [Islamic](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/IslamicCalendar.html), [Chinese](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/ChineseCalendar.html), [Japanese](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/JapaneseCalendar.html), ...), is there any date picker GUI (e.g. Swing component) that be able to use them to create displayed calendar?

Thanks

Comment: there is possible to change/set Locale, please then doesn't works ???

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2010819/230513).

Comment: @trashgod then could be works for JCalendar, or SwingX could be an alternative, because one (old) code example shows Substance with SwingX in RTL in Hebrew locale??? :-)

Comment: @mKorbel: Some support in `JLocaleChooser`. 4r1y4n: See `JCalendarDemo` for example.